# What is the proper way to Mock the SignInManager?

Tags: mocking, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

Using DotNet Core 2.0.2 to write a WebAPI, how do you test a controller that depends on `SignInManager`? I've found a few places describing how to mock up a `UserManager`, but have failed to uncover all the secrets of the `SignInManager`. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the class that I'm trying to unit test:

```
namespace API.Controllers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents an API endpoint that handles requests for client registration and authentication.
    /// </summary>
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AccountController : Controller, IAuthenticate, IRegister
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs a new instance of the AccountController class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="signInManager">Service that manages sign in operations for clients.</param>
        public AccountController(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
        {
            this.signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Authenticates the specified credentials and returns a "200 OK" and a JWT with the client's authorization claims.
        /// If the specified credentials are invalid, returns a "401 Unauthorized" HTTP response.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="credentials">Identifying properties of the client requesting access to restricted content.</param>
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(Credentials credentials)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Registers the client specified by the provided registration.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// If the registration is successful, this method also logins the client.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="registration">Identifying properties of the client requesting to have an account created.</param>
        public IActionResult Register(Registration registration)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to mock the `SignInManager` in order to verify that it is being used properly, for example:

`mockSignInManager.Verify(m => m.PasswordSignInAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), false, false), Times.Once);`

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. Read [ask] and then [edit] the question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: You don't need to. Use `TestServer` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing#integration-testing-aspnet-core)

Comment: @ChrisPratt, I've edited my question to be more specific about what I'm trying to accomplish. I am hoping to be able to unit test my controller logic; using the `TestServer` is for integration testing. Maybe, I'll have to accept that the controller can only be tested via integration testing, but I'm still hoping there's a way to properly unit test the class first.

Comment: @Nkosi, I've edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: Not without refactoring the controller to be more decoupled from implementation concerns.

Comment: Tests shouldn't be about *implementation*. Rather, you should be testing functionality. The goal is for the user to be signed in. *How* they're signed in is inconsequential. Tests that focus on a particular way of doing something are by definition brittle, and brittle tests are bad.

Comment: In other words, you simply use the test host to send a post to your sign in action with the username and password, as if the user had submitted the form. You then assert that the response contains an auth cookie or some other method of ascertaining that the user was *actually* logged in. If so, your test is successful and you can call it day. It's not important that `PasswordSignAsync` was called, with what parameters or even that `SignInManager` was utilized at all.

Comment: Unfortunately this approach is limited to standard sign-in action with username and password directly submitted by the user. It will not work with need to sign-in from external login such as Facebook login, where interaction with an external site (facebook.com) occurs. How in this case an integration test with TestServer could simulates the mandatory interaction with facebook.com?